# 3 column page with left colomn under middle content

Tags: html, css

I have created a page which has 3 columns which displays images on the sides and middle.[image] once ive uploaded it yet when i display it on my own system before i upload it displays perfect.

here is the css for the left sidebar

```
.sidebars_left {
    width:20%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:2%;
}

.sidebar{
    margin-top:2%;
    background:white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

code for left sidebar

```
 <div class="sidebars_left">
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <article>
            <a href="soul.php">
                <img src="images/chocolate/soul.png" alt="For the soul" width="80%">
            </a>
        </article>
     </aside>

<aside class="sidebar">
    <article>
        <a href="world.php">
            <img src="images/chocolate/world.jpg" alt="For the soul" width="80%">
            </a>
        </article>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here is](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/) a good explanation how to achive the same result

Comment: why not you use bootstrap to position everything nicely and divide your page more nicely :-)

Comment: i didn't know about it - i only learned the basics of html, css and php 5 or 6 years ago at college and now having to learn everything else myself (which isnt easy with dyslexia).

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style>
   div{float:left;}
   mid-div{margin-left:###;}
   </style>
```

use float:left in each div
and then give margin-left for the middle column.
you also have to define these columns width and height.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="content-left">Content 1</div>
<div class="content-middle">
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
</div>
<div class="content-right">Content 3</div>
```

```html
[class^="content-"]{
    display:table-cell;
}

.content-left{
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.content-middle{
    width: 100%;
}

.content-right{
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.content{
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```